# {Java Eclipse} How can i add multiple Layout(flow layout + Boarder layout) and give a background Jpanel?

Tags: java

I want something like this :
[image]

[image]

as you see, the scoreboard and those button can follow the border to move
and also, under them, it still has a game area, that means, it's maybe a JPanel under them?

So I want to do something like this but I don' know how to achieve it.

Here is my code so far:

```js
package Game_setup;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javafx.application.Application;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument;
import javax.swing.text.Style;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyleContext;

import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main extends JPanel implements Runnable{
 private Image Lockimage;
 private Image bitcoin;
 private Image bar;
 public static void main(String[] args){
  Main workStart = new Main();
 }
 
 public Main(){
  JFrame mframe = new JFrame();
  
  JLayeredPane MainScreen = new JLayeredPane();
  MainScreen.setLayout(null);
  //MainScreen.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,100));
  //MainScreen.setBounds(100, 100, 200, 200);
  MainScreen.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0,150));
  MainScreen.setOpaque(true);
  
  JLayeredPane Chat = new JLayeredPane();
  Chat.setLayout(null);
  Chat.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
  Chat.setBackground(new Color(255, 0, 0,70));
  Chat.setOpaque(true);

  
  //JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  //mframe.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //mframe.setIconImage(new ImageIcon (Main.class.getResource("/images/Icon.png")).getImage());
  
        setBackground(new Color(0, 255, 0,100));
        setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500);
        //setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        
        
  

  //run();
         
//         panel.setBounds(580, 760, 500, 50);
//         panel.setOpaque(false);

//         layerpane.add(panel, new Integer(1), 0);
         
         //MainScreen.add(this, new Integer(0), 0);
         
         
         
         
         JPanel mainPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
         //mainPane.setSize(100,100);
         mainPane.add(MainScreen,BorderLayout.CENTER);
         //mainPane.add(Chat,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
         
         JPanel leftPane = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT,0,mframe.getContentPane().getHeight()/2));
         leftPane.add(Chat);
         
//         layerpane.setBounds(-20, -30, 100, 100);
         //mframe.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
         //mframe.add(layerpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
         mframe.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
         mframe.add(mainPane);
         mframe.add(leftPane);
         mframe.setBounds(0,0,500,500);
         mframe.setTitle("Moon Base TD");
         mframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         //mframe.setResizable(false);
         mframe.setVisible(true);
         //mframe.pack();
         
         Lockimage = new ImageIcon (Main.class.getResource("/images/lock.jpg")).getImage();
   bitcoin = new ImageIcon (Main.class.getResource("/images/Bitcoin.png")).getImage();
   bar = new ImageIcon (Main.class.getResource("/images/bar.png")).getImage();
  
  }
 
 public void run(){
  Timer timer = new Timer();
  TimerTask myTask = new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          repaint(); 
      }
  };

  timer.schedule(myTask, 1000, 1000);

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){ 
        super.paintComponent(g);

        //g.drawImage(Lockimage, 100, 50, null);
    }
}
```

but it look like this:
[image]

Comment: group the component into different panel and add another panel as a parent panel and add `GridBagLayout` to the parent panel. Then add all the panels to parent panel with position in layout. read this - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html

Comment: But How to add different panel into it? Like create a new panel(flowLayout) and panel(boarderlauout)?